# using d3.csv to set an object's data property

Tags: javascript, oop, asynchronous, d3.js, deferred

An object that uses d3.csv() to set it's `data` property for use elsewhere. The downside is none of this works because d3.csv() is async. How can I solve this?

```
function BarChart(csvPath) {
  this.data = d3.csv('csvPath', function(csvData) {
    return csvData;
  });

  this.drawGraph = function() {
    // some code to draw a graph using this.data
  } 

  this.drawDataTable = function() {
    // some code to draw a graph using this.data
  }

  ... a bunch more code for using the data
}
```

Some code executed on page load and an event handler.

```
var barChart = new BarChart('my_data.csv');
barChart.drawGraph();

$('button.viewPreview').click(function(){
  barChart.drawDataTable();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make BarChart accept a `ready` callback (a function)

```
function BarChart(csvPath, ready) {
  var _this = this;
  d3.csv('csvPath', function(csvData) {
    _this.data = csvData
    ready()// invoke the callback
  });

  this.drawGraph = function() {
    // some code to draw a graph using this.data
  } 

  this.drawDataTable = function() {
    // some code to draw a graph using this.data
  }

  ... a bunch more code for using the data
}
```

When you instantiate barchart, supply the `ready` callback:

```
var barChart = new BarChart('my_data.csv', function() {
  barChart.drawGraph();

  $('button.viewPreview').fadeIn();// unhide the button only when ready
});


$('button.viewPreview').click(function(){
  barChart.drawDataTable();
});
```

But, IMO, it's not a great idea to make a class that's responsible for drawing a barchart also responsible for loading its data.